# Facing errors while trying to build YOCTO for orange pi-5 board

Tags: yocto, yocto-wic, yocto-kirkstone

I am trying to build YOCTO for orangepi-5b board but I am facing errors.

I have followed the steps which are mentioned in **https://github.com/JeffyCN/meta-rockchip/tree/master**. And I have added the layers required for the build in bblayers.conf and added the machine in local.conf file. But after giving the bitbake core-image-minimal command I am getting the errors mentioned below:

> WARNING: rockchip-rkbin-git-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL https://github.com/rockchip-linux/rkbin;protocol=https;branch=master, attempting MIRRORS if available
> ERROR: rockchip-rkbin-git-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1"; export NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1"; export PATH="/home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/poky/scripts:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/rockchip_rk3588_evb-poky-linux/rockchip-rkbin/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/rockchip_rk3588_evb-poky-linux/rockchip-rkbin/git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/rockchip_rk3588_evb-poky-linux/rockchip-rkbin/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/rockchip_rk3588_evb-poky-linux/rockchip-rkbin/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/rockchip_rk3588_evb-poky-linux/rockchip-rkbin/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/rockchip_rk3588_evb-poky-linux/rockchip-rkbin/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/yocto"; /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 --passive-ftp -P /home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/downloads 'https://github.com/rockchip-linux/rkbin' --progress=dot -v failed with exit code 4, no output
> ERROR: rockchip-rkbin-git-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'https://github.com/rockchip-linux/rkbin;protocol=https;branch=master')
> ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/yocto/YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/rockchip_rk3588_evb-poky-linux/rockchip-rkbin/git-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.70510
> ERROR: Task (/home/yocto/YoctoProject/meta-rockchip/recipes-bsp/rkbin/rockchip-rkbin_git.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

I have tried by changing the SRC_URI in rockchip_rkbin_git.bb file, but unable to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure with given info but seems like `SRC_URI` is in wrong format. Refer to bitbake's [git fetcher](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-fetching.html#git-fetcher-git) documentation for examples.

Try:

```
SRC_URI += "git://github.com/rockchip-linux/rkbin.git;protocol=https;branch=master"
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the info, but still facing the same issue.